# Buttons stay in hover mode after clicking/touching (mobile)

Tags: css

http://codepen.io/abdulahhamzic/pen/ALQqGq

The "start", "reset", "strict" and "spin" buttons stay in hover mode after clicking/touching them in a mobile browser. Here's the relevant CSS code:

```
button {
  background: #5c8a8a;
}
button:hover {
  background: #ffff4d!important;
}
```

So, basically, on mobile, each one of the buttons, after being touched, remains with the #ffff4d background instead of #5c8a8a, until I press somewhere else...

Comment: You can't hover with a touch screen device... You're probably looking for `active`

Answer (score 5):

In my use case, I only wanted to have the hover effect when the device *could* hover, and not have any hover effect when the device *could not* hover.

I solved this with media queries.

```css
button {
  background: #5c8a8a;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  button:hover {
    background: #ffff4d;
  }
}
```

This will only add the hover effect when the primary input of the device has the ability to hover.

---

Alternatively, if you do want *something* to happen even when on a device that doesn't have hover, it looks like `active` as suggested by [DBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898524/buttons-stay-in-hover-mode-after-clicking-touching-mobile#comment67082684_39898524) and [Andreas Boyer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39898593/5910581) is a good option.

Using media queries to have both effects, it might look something like this.

```css
button {
  background: #5c8a8a;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  button:hover {
    background: #ffff4d;
  }
}

@media (hover: none) {
  button:active {
    background: #ffff4d;
  }
}
```

This adds that background change when pressing the button on mobile (with no lingering hover effect) and keeps the hover effect on desktop.

---

Media query credit to [Kevin Powell](https://youtu.be/uuluAyw9AI0).

Answer (score -1):

```
button:active{background: #5c8a8a;}
```

Comment: Try it with an additional !important to override your :hover – or remove the !important from your :hover instead.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.